# Replacing value in xml with another string batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, findandmodify

I am new to batch scripting and I have gone through loads of posts on SO to find an answer but nothing seems to work for me. I am trying to read a xml file and extract few values and then find a string in same xml and replace with a new string I build. I have the following code, but when I run this, the test.xml I am trying to read is over written.

```
@echo off > test.xml
setLocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

Here I find the value of the URL from the xml and store it into *text*

```
 for /f "tokens=2*delims=@" %%a in (test.xml) DO set "text=%%a"&echo "%text%"
```

Then I split the value of *text* to extract the IP , port and the db name and store them in variables

```
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:" %%a in ("%text%") DO set "IP=%%a"&echo "%IP%"&set "PORT=%%b"&echo "%PORT%"&set "DB=%%c"&echo "%DB%"
```

Then I remove the end tag from DB name

```
FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=<" %%a in ("%DB%") DO set "SID=%%a"&echo "%SID%"
```

Then I set the **old** and **new** varibles to find and replace text

```
SET "old=<xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:%IP%:%PORT%:%DB%"
echo "%old%"

SET "new=<xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">%IP%</xa-datasource-property><xa-
datasource-property name="PortNumber">%PORT%</xa-datasource-property><xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">%SID%</xa-datasource-property>"
```

In the below line I actually loop through test.xml line by line, find the old text and replace it with new value,which is my aim of doing all the above.

```
 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (test.xml) do (
        set str=%%a
        ECHO str=%%str:!old!=!new!%% >> newFile.xml

    )
```

Any help is appreciated. I have spent like 3 days on this.

My content of test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>

    <xa-datasource>
        <use-java-context>false</use-java-context>
        <jndi-name>Mach9-Gateway-DS</jndi-name> 
        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-

class>
        <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:8080:oracle</xa-

datasource-property>
        <xa-datasource-property name="User">abc</xa-datasource-property>
        <xa-datasource-property name="Password">pwd</xa-datasource-property>
        <isSameRM-override-value>false</isSameRM-override-value>
        <no-recover>true</no-recover>       
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
        <exception-sorter-class-name>
            org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter
        </exception-sorter-class-name>
        <track-connection-by-tx>true</track-connection-by-tx>
        <no-tx-separate-pools />
    </xa-datasource>

</datasources>
```

In above file instead of URL property I intend to extract the IP,p ort and DB and add the xml tags for all three values as in the new string.

Comment: Kindly do not down vote this before giving it a thought, I have really gone through like almost all stuff on SO and other forums before posting a new question.

Comment: 5th code formatting is broken.

Comment: Do you absolutely want to do it via `for` and token-parsing or are you open to using an embedded vbscript/powershell code which are the proper tools for this kind of tasks?

Comment: Are you sure `ECHO str=%%str:!old!=!new!%% >> newFile.xml` shouldn't use ! instead of % to make the expansion happen during the loop?

Comment: I tried both nothing works...`set str=!str:%%old%%=%%new%%!` does not work either

Comment: `CALL ECHO str=%%str:!old!=!new!%% >> newFile.xml` should work; without `call`, the `%%` are replaced by literal `%`...